# Two floats throw TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am running into an issue with the following line of code:

`underground['distributed_load_C'] = float(ugLineList[21])*1000 + ('+' if float(ugLineList[24]) >= 0.0 else '-') + abs(float(ugLineList[24]))*1000j`

The original values pulled from ugLineList are strings and I try to type cast them into floats before addition. Even though I try to type cast them I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`

I've tried type casting them before this statement, and checking that the code snippets are truly floats:
`print type(float(ugLineList[21])*1000), type(float(ugLineList[24]))`
---> `<type 'float'> <type 'float'>`

I am really confused as to what is going on here so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your code ends up being float + str + float. The str is either '+' or '-'. Why are you adding '+' or '-'?

Comment: The two numbers are being cast to float, but the operation between them is a string (i.e. `'+'` or `'-'`).  You may want to reformulate the `if` statement so that you specifically check `ugLineList[24]` for the sign, then do the right operation by explicitly using the right arithmetic operator.

Comment: I had a feeling it was a problem with the if statement, typecasting and checking the sign before doing the operation worked. In hindsight, I am not sure why I added the condition for adding or subtracting per Alg_D's answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment above (you are adding the string '+' or '-' depending on the value of ugLineList[24]) is exactly correct. Assuming you intend to add or subtract

```
abs(float(ugLineList[24]))*1000j
```

based on the evaluation of your if statement, you could do something like:

```
res = float(ugLineList[21])*1000
if float(ugLineList[24]) >= 0.0:
   res += abs(float(ugLineList[24]))*1000j
else:
   res -= abs(float(ugLineList[24]))*1000j
underground['distributed_load_C'] = res
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have strings while trying to do an aritmetic operation

```
+ ('+' if float(ugLineList[24]) >= 0.0 else '-')
```

like **'+'**

do you really need the condition? `'+' if float(ugLineList[24]) >= 0.0`

try yo cast individual variales and do the operations with them before put all in one line

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do by checking the sign of the value and then performing an `abs`, but I would bet that you can simply drop it:

```
underground['distributed_load_C'] = float(ugLineList[21])*1000 + float(ugLineList[24])*1000j
```